# Q: Adding stroke to circular TextView on button click

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to implement my own color picker and I want to make stroke around the color when its clicked. But i have to do it programmatically which is difficult for me.. If someone can give me a hand that would be great

layout.xml

```
<TableRow style="@style/colour_palette_row">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/col_1"
        style="@style/colour_palette_button"
        android:background="#48ff00"
        android:text="@string/number_one" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/col_2"
        style="@style/colour_palette_button"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_textview"
        android:text="@string/number_two" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/col_3"
        style="@style/colour_palette_button"
        android:text="@string/number_three" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/col_4"
        style="@style/colour_palette_button"
        android:text="@string/number_four" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/col_5"
        style="@style/colour_palette_button"
        android:text="@string/number_five" />

</TableRow>
```

drawable/rounded_textview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/circle" />
</selector>
```

drawable/circle.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#9FE554" />
    <size
        android:height="60dp"
        android:width="60dp" />
</shape>
```

Also currently i'm using new file for each color if there are some suggestions about that it would be nice.